# Set the value of <input type="date"... in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

Don't understand why this isn't working. I have a simple 'input type="date"' field as such....

```
<input type="date" name="Date"/>
```

And I'm trying to set the value to todays date whenever the page loads with this function...

```
function setDate(date){
    z=$(date).attr('value');

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} 
    if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} 
    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;     

    $(date).attr('value',today);
}
```

I've done the normal debugging and I know this function is being called and I know that the variable 'today' does in fact hold todays date in the form 'yyyy-mm-dd'. I have tried doing all different types of date formats (dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, etc.)

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Try `$(date).val(today)`.

Comment: also, use `prop`. `attr` is deprecated.

Comment: Also, what's `date`?. I'm supposing it is already a DOM element or selector right? Otherwise `$(date)` must be the problem.

Comment: It's the id of the date, I forgot to include it in my example.

Comment: @Colleen - Where did you see that attr is deprecated? That's news to me. attr and prop are similar but not interchangeable. Each has its own use case(s).

Comment: @Steve http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop- "deprecated the use of .attr() to set properties." which is exactly what OP is trying to do.

Comment: In fact, exactly specific to this situation: "The value property versus attribute on input elements is another example of this ambiguity. The attribute generally reflects the value that was read from the HTML markup; the property reflects the current value. Since the .val() method is the recommended jQuery way to get or set the values of form elements, this confusion usually does not affect users.

However, when a selector like "input[value=abc]" is used, it should always select by the value attribute and not any change made to the property by the user..."

Comment: @Colleen - I might be wrong, but I don't see the mentioning of "deprecating" of `attr()` anywhere.  Your link only clarifies the correct use of `attr()` vs. `prop()` vs. `val()` and how 1.9 has cleaned up some inconsistency in the code.  Your link even lists the correct use of `attr()` in a couple of examples.

Comment: @Steve did you read the first word of my first quote?!

Comment: You are correct. The use of `attr()` to "set properties" is deprecated. And rightfully so.  But in your comment above, you state "`attr` is deprecated", which is simply incorrect. `attr` still is very much in use.  Maybe not for what the OP is asking, but stating it is deprecated is wrong. That's all I am saying.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I see what you're saying. Fair enough.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For input just use **.val()**

To **read the value**

```
  z=$(date).val();
```

To **set the value**

```
$(date).val(today);
```

Comment: @Hoser if that worked you should give Sushanth answer credit.

Comment: What happens if the browser doesn't support the date input type?

Comment: Its giving null everytime , date is not fetched @Sushanth--

Comment: @sushanth my date value is in the form of   yyyy-mm-dd...each time the user passes it is stored in a variable "dat".....  eg:  var dat="2013-05-16" and I have to make this date set as default in the Date picker ...i tried $(date).val(dat)...but it's not working;

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[name=Date]').val(today);
```